# Word choice synonym for exempts/supersedes

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, is-it-a-word

So I'm working on a research project where I need a particular word a lot, but I'm not sure if the word I'm using is proper, or if there's a better choice.

Some background, regular T cells need to be activated by something called MHC, but CAR T cells do not need to be activated this way.

So one sentence I have been saying is that

> CAR T cells *exempt* MHC activation

But then I tried *supersedes* and it still doesn't have the right sound to it.

Word help please :).

Answer (score 2):

**obviate** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/obviate)

> vb (tr) to avoid or prevent (a need or difficulty)

As in:

> CAR T cells obviate the need for MHC activation.

Comment: equinox has found the right word, so I am up voting it.  However, what is wrong with simply saying: “...CAR cells do not need MHC activation?  Quite a few non-native users of English would be saved having to go to a dictionary.